# Qt Creator cannot build anything

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have Qt Creator, from the About dialog:

```
Qt Creator 3.6.1
Based on Qt 5.6.0 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64 bit)

Built on Mar 14 2016 09:35:54

From revision 5587df79a1
```

I have been working for months on a number of projects which until today compiled without problems, I am using Qt 5.6.0, sometime this morning an error has occurred. At first glance I thought it was something in my project, however having searched and compared versions in Git I could not find any problems. I then tried to build other projects and the same errors came up. I then sought help in-house from another Qt developer we tried building one of the examples 'terminal' this also now shows the same errors, for some unexplained reason I cannot build any projects on my development system.

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.2 (Maipo)

I did a RedHat system update earlier today, however I had compiled and build projects post this update, then all of a sudden something has happened that stops the build process, typical errors displayed when trying to build:

```
In file included from /home/fcs/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:40:0,
from /home/fcs/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qapplication.h:37,
from /home/fcs/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/QApplication:1,
from ../terminal/main.cpp:35:
/home/fcs/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:90:17: error: field 'children' has incomplete type
QObjectList children;
^
/home/fcs/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h: In member function 'const QObjectList& QObject::children() const':
/home/fcs/Qt/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:190:64: error: 'class QObjectData' has no member named 'children'
inline const QObjectList &children() const { return d_ptr->children; }
```

Is there a clean up or built in integrity check/repair tool I can run that will fix whatever is wrong?

I am currently running the Qt Maintenance tool, hoping that this will find and resolve any issues, it is presently downloading 1.2GB of updates.

To be very clear, this issue is not related to my project, the behaviour does the same with a stock project from the Qt examples.  So something is now broken and I would like to know how to fix it.

Comment: Since the last time it worked and now, what have you done? Not only with the code but with your system? Have you updated anything? Removed or installed some software? Had someone else do something?

Comment: Can you do a simple "Hello World!"-Test?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, as mentioned in the post, RedHat was updated, but it did work after the update.

Comment: @arc_lupus, no applications compile, not even stock project examples.

Comment: Did you `#include <QObjectList>`?

Comment: @tobilocker, As posted I didn't change anything this was a project that built without issues, and its not related to my project, even it I open a stock project that I have never modified it does the same.

Comment: @SPlatten: Is qmake working, i.e. if you just run it from the command line, and on an example?

Comment: @arc_lupus, I tried running qmake and this runs without issue, but trying to build after qmake results in the errors.

Comment: Hm well that is weird since the error is pretty obvious, as you said

Comment: @tobilocker, I agree, its like someone has pulled the rug from under my feet.

Comment: Computers just don't do things on their own, something must have been done to stop your project from building. Did you have an unclean shutdown or computer crash (power outage maybe)? Are the hard-drive statuses okay? Nothing in the system logs that can tell you what happened? There's really nothing we can do to help you, not without more information and that might make this a question more for Super User instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: As for possible ways to solve this, have you tried reinstalling Qt? Possibly with removing it first?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, as stated in my post the ONLY thing that was done was a RedHat update, "sudo yum update", then "sudo yum upgrade", but it did work for a while after this.

Comment: When the Qt Maintenance completes I'm hoping it will work, will post either way.

Comment: I managed to make the same error happen by removing the following include from `qobject.h`: `#include <QtCore/qlist.h>`.

Comment: @thuga, thank you, not sure what happened but after running the maintenance tool it is all now as it was and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the Qt Maintenance tool and allowing it to complete the update of all software, everything now works again, I have no idea what caused it to fail other than a possible conflict with one of the system updates.